# Creating folder unzipping epub in Android

Tags: java, android, directory, unzip, epub

I have read a lot of threads on this site regarding my issue, and the code I have is based off some of them. The problem I have currently is that unzipping an ePub results in only the mimetype file being extracted with LogCat getting errors in creating a folder from what I understand.

Following is what I use to decompress any zip file, I got it from [Problem when Unzipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061943/problem-when-unzipping):

```
/**
 * @author jon
 */
public class Decompress {
    private String _zipFile;
    private String _location;
    ZipEntry ze = null;

    public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) {
        _zipFile = zipFile;
        _location = location;

        _dirChecker("");
    }

    public void unzip() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    _dirChecker(ze.getName());
                } else {
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location
                            + ze.getName());
                    for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                        fout.write(c);
                    }

                    zin.closeEntry();
                    fout.close();
                }

            }
            zin.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
        }

    }

    private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
        File f = new File(_location + dir);

        Log.d("Decompress", f.getAbsolutePath().toString());

        if (!f.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

Other articles I have referred to:
    [Unzip a zipped file on sd card in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697466/unzip-a-zipped-file-on-sd-card-in-android-application)
    [Why my decompress class don't make directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195125/why-my-decompress-class-dont-make-directories)
    [Uzip folders recursively -android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747468/uzip-folders-recursively-android#)
    [Render epub files in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640728/render-epub-files-in-android)
    [Android EPUBLIB read/load content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038228/android-epublib-read-load-content)

Here is the LogCat Error I receive on the second file(/folder) after the mimetype file.

```
03-24 10:38:13.991: E/Decompress(23190): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/unzipped/yamani/CDS-suggestions.docx: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I'm currently using a regular zip file to test out my code.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve my problem by using another snippet found on this site.

Source:

```
public class unpackZip {
    public boolean unzip(String zipname, String path) {
        InputStream is;
        ZipInputStream zis;
        try {
            String filename;
            is = new FileInputStream(zipname);
            zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
            ZipEntry ze;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                // zapis do souboru
                filename = ze.getName();

                // Need to create directories if not exists, or
                // it will generate an Exception...
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    File fmd = new File(path, filename);
                    fmd.mkdirs();
                    continue;
                } else {
                    // Make this part of the code more efficient .code-revise
                    File fmd = new File(path, filename);
                    Log.d("Unzipping", fmd.getParentFile().getPath());
                    String parent = fmd.getParentFile().getPath();

                    File fmd_1 = new File(parent);
                    fmd_1.mkdirs();
                    // end of .code-revise
                }

                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

                // cteni zipu a zapis
                while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }

                fout.close();
                zis.closeEntry();
            }

            zis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```